# Matrix norm of product equal implies equality in norms of factors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Given a matrix $A$, if 
$$\|Av\|_1=\|Aw\|_1$$
for given vectors $v$ and $w$, then does $\|v\|_1=\|w\|_1$? 
Here $\|\,\cdot\,\|_1$ denotes the $L^1$ norm.

Comment: Does $L^1$ norm refer to $\max_{1\leq j\leq n}\sum_{i=1}^m|a_{ij}|$?

Comment: Yes, or $\max_{1\leq j\leq n}\sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij}$ if you prefer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think so. Consider the following example, let
\begin{equation}
A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2&0\\
0&1
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}
and $v=(2,1)^\top$, $w=(1.5,2)^\top$. Then $\|Av\|_1=\|Aw\|_1=5$. But $\|w\|_1=3.5$ while $\|v\|_1=3$. So personally, your proposition is false.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I wonder if there is any refinement of this statement so that it holds...

Comment: I think it is complicated. The condition I can think of is all eigenvalues of $A$ are same. In that case, I think your proposition can be holds. But I can not generalize it in general case.